# Not member rule doesn't work as expected in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog, logic, negation, prolog-dif

I am attempting to create a maze program in Prolog, whereby the aim is to find a route from the start of the maze to a point in the centre of the maze called m. The maze consists of squares which are connected using one of four colours: Blue, Green, Purple or Orange. The route from start to the centre follows a repeating pattern of the four colours.

I have created the following code:

```
link2(A, Colour, B) :- link(A, Colour, B).       
link2(A, Colour, B) :- link(B, Colour, A).

changecolour(blue,green).
changecolour(green,purple).
changecolour(purple,orange).
changecolour(orange,blue).

route(A, Colour1, B, List2) :-
    link2(A, Colour1, B),
    append([A], [B], List2).
route(A, Colour1, B, List2) :-
    link2(A, Colour1, X),
    changecolour(Colour1,Colour2),
    append([A], List, List2),
    \+ member(A, List),
    route(X, Colour2, B, List).
```

For some reason, the code isn't working as expected and I'm not sure why. I have a feeling its something to do with the negation(not member) rule but can someone advise what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is it doing, and what were you expecting?

Comment: Use `maplist(dif(A), Ls)` to express, in a purely logical way, that `A` is not in the list `Ls`.

Comment: I'm aiming for the prolog to print out the route from start to m, however, when I run the trace, Prolog asks whether start is a member of a list which is just a variable, _G449 so returns >    Exit: (8) lists:member(start, [start|_G452]) ? creep. Exit means success, but since we have “not member” in this instance, exiting member successfully means to fail here. "Not member" should only fail if the program comes back to a square that has already been visited.

Comment: Ask Java? Just an aside: instead of `append([A], List, List2)` you can just say, `[A|List] = List2`, and instead of `append([A], [B], List2)`, just, `[A,B] = List2`, or briefer still: `route(A, Colour1, B, [A,B]) :- link2(A, Colour1, B).` (NOTE: you have a typo and wrote `Colou1` instead of `Colour1`).

Comment: So I replace    \+ member(A, List)  with maplist(dif(A), Ls)?

Comment: No, you'd replace `\+ member(A, List)` with `maplist(dif(A), List)`.

Comment: @lurker There are definitely many answers on SO by mat, false, repeat that use this idiom.

Comment: @m.lewis1995 You still haven't said what query you entered, what result you got, and what result you expected.

Comment: @Boris yeah somehow I missed that specific form. Not sure why. Bad eyesight I guess... or bad memory. Time for me to go back to my cave. :p

Comment: The query was ?-route(Start, Blue, m, List2). I expected it to output the route from start to m (there are many cycles and I believe that there are many steps in this route). The query returned false.

Comment: @lurker I've only noticed it because usually, you either want `\+ memberchk` if you know the list is ground, or then really `maplist(dif)` if you don't. `\+ member` is not too useful I guess?

Comment: @m.lewis1995 that query will be a problem. `Blue` is a variable. Did you mean `route(Start, blue, m, List2).`?

Comment: Apologies, you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

You defined `changecolour` and never used it; you used `nextcolour` but never defined it.

Comment: This was an error when I typed my query into Stack overflow. It was correct in the program.

Comment: @m.lewis1995 it would help a great deal if you copy/paste the actual code into your question that you're having trouble with.

Comment: @m.lewis1995 not necessarily *all* of the code, but at least what you put there should be accurate.