# Error with Recursion In prolog

Tags: recursion, prolog, maze

I am attempting to create a maze program in Prolog, whereby the aim is to find a route from the start of the maze to a point in the centre of the maze called m. The maze consists of squares which are connected using one of four colours: Blue, Green, Purple or Orange. The route from start to the centre follows a repeating pattern of the four colours.

I have created the following code:

```
l2(A, Colour, B) :- link(A, Colour, B).       
l2(A, Colour, B) :- link(B, Colour, A).

changecolour(blue, green).
changecolour(green, purple).
changecolour(purple, orange).
changecolour(orange, blue).

route(A, Colour1, B, List2) :-
    l2(A, Colour1, B),
    append([A], [B], List2).

route(A, Colour1, B, List2) :-
    l2(A, Colour1, X),
    changecolour(Colour1, Colour2),
    append([A], List, List2)
    \+ member(A, List),
    route(X, Colour2, B, List).
```

For some reason, the code isn't working as expected and I'm not sure why. I have a feeling its something to do with the negation(not member) rule but can someone advise what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on *the code isn't working as expected*? What query did you perform, what result expected, and what did you actually see?

Comment: You're missing a comma after `append([A], List, List2)` by the way. Also note you don't need `append/3` in your case. Appending `[A]` to `[B]` is just `[A,B]` (so `List2 = [A,B]` would suffice), and appending `[A]` to `List` results in `[A|List]` (so `List2 = [A|List]` would suffice). This was all explained in comments to your [prior question on the same code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36866460/not-member-rule-doesnt-work-as-expected-in-prolog), which appears to be a duplicate question.